# Query Activity for ORDER BY xxx DESC LIMIT

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions

I'm trying to create a query activity in order to show, from a Data Extension, only the last 5 articles ids.
I tried with the formula `ORDER BY xxx DESC LIMIT 0,5` as in SQL but it is not working and it is returning this exception:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified

How can I use `ORDER BY` in a Data Extension?

Comment: Can you please share your complet soql?

Answer (score 2):

In SFMC, you'll need to specify `top` if you want to use an `order by` -- as the error suggests.  For example if you want to select a random row in a Data Extension, you can use a  query like this:

```
select top 1
column1
, column2
from DataExtension1
order by newid()
```

Comment: Hi Adams,
thanks to reply.
This is the query that I used:

SELECT Browser_History_Items*
FROM Browser_History_Items
ORDER BY Unique_Journey_ID DESC LIMIT 0,5

I will try with your suggestion and I will let you know.

Comment: FYI, Query Activities in SFMC follow Transact-SQL (SQLServer) syntax.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks a lot to reply.
I couldn't find any solution to my question in other topics. I tried to use check and try in my Query Activity but everything seems not working.