# SQL Query activity Order by function

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I want to order the result of my query result and put it via Query activity into a data extension (DE has no primary key). The order by MAWE is pretty important for me.

```
select 
count (SubscriberKey) AS amount,
country,
MAWE,
variant 
from Sendfinal1 
group by country,MAWE,variant 
order by MAWE,country
```

SF seems not to accept the order by:

> Message: An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: The ORDER
>   BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables,
>   subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR
>   XML is also specified.

Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: have you checked this topic? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/187273/how-to-use-sql-order-by-statement-in-marketing-cloud-error-says-requires-top

Comment: Or you can take help from https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/128706/query-activity-for-order-by-xxx-desc-limit/128713

Comment: As a quick but dirty workaround, you could use `SELECT TOP 9223372036854775807` in the first line to get all the records

Comment: A `select top 100 percent` will also work

Comment: @AdamSpriggs I thought so as well, but couldn't get the `PERCENT` to work..

Comment: @Zuzannamj - Yeah, I noticed it does not work at all (`PERCENT`) in Query Studio, BUT it works fine in a real query. TOP 100 PERCENT is viable, just not in query studio

Comment: Sweet, as if I needed another reason to dislike Query Studio.

Comment: @Gortonington gotcha, thanks!!